# NPM Command Not Found in bash command

Tags: npm, npm-install

I made the mistake of updating npm today and now whenever I try to use any commands that start with npm the terminal returns with "npm: command not found."  I am running node -v 13.13.0, I have tried to install npm again however, any time I use npm the terminal returns "npm: command not found."  I am using bash in the terminal.  Does anyone have any ideas how to troubleshoot this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: did you try to reinstall npm?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I had to reinstall node.js, didn't think to try that first, my bad.